# Why am I getting the same result in different elements with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a simple question. I am not sure why - maybe a really silly mistake - but I couldn't figure out why this code gives me the same result.

The code:

```
rows = table.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@role='row']")
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
        print(row.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@role="gridcell"][1]'))
        print(row.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@role="gridcell"][1]/span'))
        print(row.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@role="gridcell"][1]/span/a[1]'))
        name = row.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@role="gridcell"][1]/span/a[1]')
```

The output:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0f06562267ccaa7755c3e9a20542161e", element="8828F8096DD88B9082D0630AAD96DF91_element_74")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0f06562267ccaa7755c3e9a20542161e", element="8828F8096DD88B9082D0630AAD96DF91_element_96")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0f06562267ccaa7755c3e9a20542161e", element="8828F8096DD88B9082D0630AAD96DF91_element_97")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0f06562267ccaa7755c3e9a20542161e", element="8828F8096DD88B9082D0630AAD96DF91_element_98")>

<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0f06562267ccaa7755c3e9a20542161e", element="8828F8096DD88B9082D0630AAD96DF91_element_75")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0f06562267ccaa7755c3e9a20542161e", element="8828F8096DD88B9082D0630AAD96DF91_element_96")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0f06562267ccaa7755c3e9a20542161e", element="8828F8096DD88B9082D0630AAD96DF91_element_97")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0f06562267ccaa7755c3e9a20542161e", element="8828F8096DD88B9082D0630AAD96DF91_element_98")>
```

As you can see, the row is different but after everything is same, what is the problem here? (It is like this for every row in rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `xpath` with a root element (`row`) you must always start the xpath with `./` so that it will find elements relative to `row`.

1. Will search the whole DOM and not relative to `row`

   `row.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@role="gridcell"][1]')`
2. Will search the element relative to `row`

   `row.find_element(By.XPATH, './*[@role="gridcell"][1]')`

Basically, the first example is just the same as calling

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@role="gridcell"][1]')
```

Comment: It gives error such that couldnt find the XPATH

Comment: I do not know how exactly your DOM that are parsing look like, you can try `row.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@role="gridcell"][1]')` if the gridcell is not an immediate element of row

Comment: Well seems like I was getting rows wrongly and that is why it was giving me the error. I fixed it and now it works like a charm and your answer is correct. And I think this question is a duplicate one now. Thanks